# Can the weight of something be a number with a repeating decimal?

Tags: measure-theory

This was brought up at my work today and I believe that it can be.  My co-workers think that this is a crazy notion and I can't explain why weight can be a repeating decimal to their satisfaction.

I apologize if this question is too simplistic for this site or if I've tagged it incorrectly.  Any help with this would be greatly appreciated even if I'm wrong.  Thank you.

Comment: You mean like $1/3$ of a pound?

Comment: If you have something that weighs _exactly_ $\frac13$ kilogram, then its weight is a repeating decimal. But how would you know? For that matter, how can you tell that an object weighs exactly $2$ kilograms (infinite repeating zeros after the decimal point)?

Comment: Good point David thanks

Answer (score 4):

Since the units of a measurement will almost always be in some sense arbitrary or synthetic, i.e. "man-made" such as pounds, kilos, metres, celsius etc, then if you have, say, three identical objects whose weight together is "exactly" 1 pound, then each of them must have a mass of 1/3 of a pound, clearly a repeating decimal. However, when talking about real physical measurements, there must *always* be some notion of precision in the measurement. It is simply not possible to measure the mass (or length or speed or whatever) of an object to arbitrary precision, and so in the example above, you just can't measure that exact total, as there will always be some uncertainty in any measurement you make.

Comment: Yes Joel and thank you very much Danimal.

Answer (score 1):

In the real world, error is unavoidable. One cannot measure (continuous) quantities with infinite precision, which is what is necessary in order to have a "real" repeating decimal(though if you have absolutely nothing, a trivial exception would be 0.000...). When we talk about having a "third" of something, we don't *actually* mean 1/3 in the mathematical sense, which is equivalent to 0.333..., but rather that we've measured some quantity which is *close* to 1/3. How close depends on, of course, our measurement.